# How to manually set language in ASP MVC without reconfiguring routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization

### EDIT

The mistake was in the country code. Albania's country code is `sq-AL`, and not `al-AL`.
For a full list of country codes: http://timtrott.co.uk/culture-codes/

---

I don't need to have different routing for different languages. 
All I need is by the click of a button to toggle between two languages, Albanian, and English.

What I can't figure out: how to change the language? I'm not worried on how to detect which language needs to be selected, but how to actually change the language.

I have these 2 resource files:
Resources.resx, Resources.al-AL.resx

Always the strings from Resources.resx are used, how can I change so that the strings from Resources.al-AL.resx are used?

I tried something like this:

```
//I'm just trying stuff I read here in SO, none worked so far.
Resource.Culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("al-AL");
HttpContext.Session["culture"] = "al-AL";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("al-AL");
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

And in my view I have this:

```
@Resource.Culture
@Html.Label(Resource.CustomerName, new { @class = "control-label"})
```

When I first open the view, the first line is empty, after selecting one of the buttons to change the language, I verify that the Resource's culture is being changed, but the text stays the same.

EDIT:

I even added this to `web.config` `<globalization uiCulture="al-AL" culture="al-AL"/>`

Custom folder to hold the resource files

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using culture code `al-AL` I had to use `sq-AL`. For a full list of culture codes:

http://timtrott.co.uk/culture-codes/